# Unexpected error "incorrect use of identifier" when running DXL code

Tags: ibm-doors

I have a script which calls functions from this script:

https://www.baselinesinc.com/dxl-repository/?filerepoaction=showpost&filepost_id=13

which is distributed under the LGPL. I have found several references to this script online, indicating that it works. For my own purposes, I removed the part of the code which executes on load (some 20 lines at the bottom of the file) and converted the file to an .inc, to serve as a library. I haven't done any other changes.

My own script **has worked for a few months at this point**. But now, all of a sudden, when I try to run it, I get these errors:

```
-E- DXL: <DOORSImporter\Import_From_Excel.inc:291> incorrect use of identifier (rtfValue)
-E- DXL: <DOORSImporter\Import_From_Excel.inc:292> incorrect use of identifier (nonRTFValue)
-E- DXL: <DOORSImporter\Import_From_Excel.inc:346> incorrect use of identifier (temp)
-E- DXL: <DOORSImporter\Import_From_Excel.inc:464> incorrect use of identifier (columnHeading)
-E- DXL: <DOORSImporter\Import_From_Excel.inc:1127> incorrect use of identifier (cellValue)
-I- DXL: All done. Errors reported: 5. Warnings reported: 0.
```

Below is a snippet of code which shows this error. I marked lines 291 and 292

```
bool richTextTruncated(int rowNumber, int columnNumber) {
   Buffer rtfValue = create
   Buffer nonRTFValue = create

   rtfValue = ""
   nonRTFValue = ""

   rtfValue = copyRichTextFromCell(""intToCol(columnNumber) "" rowNumber"")   // get the rich text
   rtfValue = trimWhitespace(stripRichText(tempStringOf(rtfValue)))   // strip off RTF formatting.   <----- 291
   nonRTFValue = trimWhitespace(getCellValue(rowNumber, columnNumber))                             //<----- 292

   if(tempStringOf(rtfValue) != tempStringOf(nonRTFValue)) {   // if the two strings aren't equal
      delete(rtfValue)
      delete(nonRTFValue)
      return true                           // return that text was truncated
   }

   delete(rtfValue)
   delete(nonRTFValue)
   return false
}
```

The function trimWhitespace itself is defined as
`string trimWhitespace(string s)` so it's OK to assign its output to a buffer.

So this is all very confusing because, like I said, this has worked and the code has not been changed (last check in of the file `DOORSImporter\Import_From_Excel.inc` is from last November, whereas I have used the script even in January.

Our IT department might have updated DOORS recently, I don't know. I checked the latest version of the dxl reference manual for any recent changes which might have caused this, but I couldn't find any change to the way buffers are handled.
To be fair, I have found working with buffers quite confusing. In my own code, I ended up discarding them altogether. However, the script Import_From_Excel has worked unchanged for a long time now.

Any support with this will be greatly appreciated.

********** Edit 27.02.2020 **************

The function `copyRichTextFromCell` is defined as below. Its sourced is from the link below.
https://www.baselinesinc.com/dxl-repository/?filerepoaction=showpost&filepost_id=10

```
string copyRichTextFromCell(string loc) {
   if(!getCell(loc)) {
      return("error");
   }

   if(!checkResult(oleMethod(objCell, cMethodSelect)))   {  // selects the cell
      return("error");
   }

   if(!checkResult(oleMethod(objCell, cMethodCopy))) {      // copies the contents of the cell to the clipboard
      return("error");
   }

   return stringOf(richClip)
}
```

********** Edit 28.02.2020 **************

The function `trimWhitespace` is as below.

```
string trimWhitespace(string s) {
   int first = 0;
   int last = length(s) - 1;

   while(last > 0 && (isspace(s[last]) || s[last] == '\n' || s[last] == '\r' || s[last] == '\t')) {
      last--;
   }
   while(isspace(s[first]) && first < last) {
      first++;
   }
   if(s[first:last] == " ") {
      return("");
   }
   return(s[first:last]);
}
```

While playing around, I discovered that if I modify as below, one of the errors disappears. It is beyond me as to why that might happen, because the code is equivalent, as far as I can tell...

```
bool richTextTruncated(int rowNumber, int columnNumber) {
   Buffer rtfValue = create
   Buffer nonRTFValue = create
   string fooString

   rtfValue = ""
   nonRTFValue = ""

   rtfValue = copyRichTextFromCell(""intToCol(columnNumber) "" rowNumber"")   // get the rich text


   fooString = trimWhitespace(stripRichText(tempStringOf(rtfValue)))
   rtfValue = fooString   // strip off RTF formatting.
   fooString = trimWhitespace(getCellValue(rowNumber, columnNumber))
   nonRTFValue = fooString


   if(tempStringOf(rtfValue) != tempStringOf(nonRTFValue)) {   // if the two strings aren't equal
      delete(rtfValue)
      delete(nonRTFValue)
      return true                           // return that text was truncated
   }

   delete(rtfValue)
   delete(nonRTFValue)
   return false
}
```

So the lines with fooString do not throw an error anymore. In the initial version, these lines were just e.g. `rtfValue = trimWhitespace(stripRichText(tempStringOf(rtfValue)))` and this *would* throw an error.

Comment: Could you post the code for the function copyRichTextFromCell()?

Comment: Sure. Please see at the bottom of the initial post.

Comment: Just to make sure I cover my bases- do you access DOORs via some kind of terminal server / some way that involves sharing a clipboard? And, if so, is that turned on?

Comment: Actually, yes, I am running it through a remote desktop connection. And clipboard sharing was indeed active. But I just tried it now _without_ shared clipboard and the behavior was the same. Also, other DXL scripts work fine. I have added the function `trimWhitespace` it to the additional post, in case it helps. However, not all instances where the function is called trigger the error. There are 4 instances in the same script which do not. I can't tell that they have any meaningful differences...

Comment: While playing around, I discovered one more very interesting thing. I described it at the bottom of the original post.

Comment: So I used this last discovery to actually fix my problem (or, at least, work around it). Wherever I had `someBufferVariable = trimWhitespace(someStringVariable)` and an error, I replaced with `someOtherStringVariable = trimWhitespace(someStringVariable) ; someBufferVariable = someOtherStringVariable`. And the errors are gone. Can't imagine why this is necessary, though.